# Excel VB: how do I call VLOOKUP if condition is met?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a data set that comes out of Oracle, but a number of the records are missing the GEO data (AMER, EMEA, APAC) in column E and instead show "-".    I am formatting and processing this data using VB and I have everything working save for this one piece.

What I want to do is to call a VLOOKUP formula to replace those "-" values with the correct GEO based on the country name shown in column J.  All records with GEOs already present should be bypassed.   The code I built for this overwrites every record, unfortunately:

```
For z = 1 To LR
    x = Application.VLookup(Cells(z, "J"), Sheets("MasterTerritoryList").Columns("A:F"), 6, False)
    If Not (IsError(x)) Then
       Cells(z, "E").Value = x
    End If
Next z
```

Can someone help me out by showing me how to read the data in column E and replace only those values that equal "-"?

Many thanks!!

Comment: Insert a check, `If Cells(z, "E").Value = "-" then Cells(z, "E").Value = x` This way you will not overwrite existing records

Comment: Thanks very much, Siddharth!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  For z = 1 To LR
      If Cells(z, "E").text = "-" Then ' <-------- Add this test
        X = Application.VLookup(Cells(z, "J"), Sheets("MasterTerritoryList").Columns("A:F"), 6, False)
        If Not (IsError(X)) Then Cells(z, "E").Value = X
      End If
  Next z
```

Comment: A big ole' internet high five to you, A.S.H.   This works a treat.  Thank you very much!!!